# jQuery if statement show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, innerhtml

I got a code like this that copies inside text to another div.

```
 var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('myModal');
 var MyDiv2 = document.getElementById('purchaseNotice');
 MyDiv2.innerHTML = MyDiv1.innerHTML;
```

The div with id 'purchaseNotice' is sitting within a template, it also has a styling class of the box, however I need to create an if statement that checks if the id 'myModal' exist then show 'purchaseNotice' with class (else) hide it all.

If there was a way of adding a div with class between the text that is copied to 'purchaseNotice' that would solve my problem.

**@UPDATE**

Here is a link to what I have:
http://jsfiddle.net/A9FE8/

Try to make an if statement to show the styling of the 'infobox' only if the id 'myModal' exist, otherwise hide.

Comment: Adding a class? You can't just use `$("#purchaseNotice").attr("class", "asdf")` or `addClass()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean like:

```
if( $("#myModal").length ) { //check if div with id "myModal" exists
  $("#purchaseNotice").addClass("some_class").show();
}
else {
   $("#purchaseNotice").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
var myDiv1 = $('#myModal'),
    myDiv2 = $('#purchaseNotice');

if (myDiv1.get(0)) { // div exists
  myDiv2.html(myDiv1.html()).show();
} else {
  myDiv2.hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than copying one div to another to show it, you could simply show/hide it via `elem.style.display = true; /*show*/` or `elem.style.display = false; /*hide*/`;

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/JWells/HfqTe/) is a fiddle/example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Javascript**

```
var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('myModal');
if(MyDiv1.length) {
   document.getElementById('purchaseNotice').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('purchaseNotice').innerHTML= MyDiv1.innerHTML
} else {
   document.getElementById('purchaseNotice').style.display='none';
}
```

**Jquery**

```
if($('#myModal').length) {
   $('#purchaseNotice').html($('#myModal').html()) // set html
                       .show(); // show purchaseNotice div
} else {
   $('#purchaseNotice').hide();
}
```